# Gulp-Inject Positions

Tags: gulp, gulp-inject

If I want to inject Js Files in diff. locations e.g. `<head> here` and `here </body>`. I need to set names like described here for the injections:
https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject#method-2-use-gulp-injects-name-option

```
  <!-- head:js -->
  <!-- only importantFile.js will be injected here -->
  <!-- endinject -->
```

How can I modify this selector, that I don't have to name each file. E.g. take all files which contain *_important.js

```
.pipe(inject(gulp.src('./src/importantFile.js', {read: false}), {name: 'head'}))
```

And is there a better way. E.g. like adding s.th. inside the javascript file or name it like this orderModule.above.js, googleAnalytics.below.js

Answer (score 0):

From the `gulp` [documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpsrcglobs-options):

`gulp.src(globs[, options])` - Emits files matching provided glob or an array of globs.

You therefore have tremendous freedom to define how you want to differentiate between "important" files and others.

```
.pipe(inject(gulp.src('*_important.js')))
.pipe(inject(gulp.src('*.head.js')))
```

etc. Then just provide the negation of this pattern in the second `gulp.src` call

```
.pipe(inject(gulp.src(['*.js', '!*_important.js'])))
.pipe(inject(gulp.src(['*.js', '!*.head.js'])))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gulp.task('dev', function () {
  var target = gulp.src('./index.html');
  return target
    .pipe(inject(gulp.src('_MAIN_CSS_FILES_', {read: false})))
    .pipe(inject(gulp.src('_BOWER_CSS_FILES_', {read: false}), {name: 'bower'}))
    .pipe(inject(gulp.src('_MAIN_JS_FILES_', {read: false})))
    .pipe(inject(gulp.src('_BOWER_JS_FILES_', {read: false}), {name: 'bower'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dest/"));
});
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>

    <!-- inject:css -->
    <!-- built css files will go here... -->
    <!-- endinject -->

    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- bower installed css files will go here... -->
    <!-- endinject -->

</head>
<body>


<!-- bower:js -->
<!-- bower installed js files will go here... -->
<!-- endinject -->

<!-- inject:js -->
<!-- built js files will go here... -->
<!-- endinject -->

</body>
</html>
```